# fail2ban not creating jails in CentOS

Tags: centos, centos7, fail2ban, asterisk

I'm trying to create a jail in Fail2Ban to protect a Asterisk PBX.
I already did as suggested and made a copy of `jail.conf` named `jail.local`. In `jail.local`, I set up a asterisk jail as follows:

```
[asterisk]

port     = 5060,5061
action_  = %(default/action_)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, protocol="tcp"]
           %(default/action_)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, protocol="udp"]
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages
maxretry = 10
```

Then, in `jail.d` folder, I created a file called `asterisk.full`:

```
[asterisk-full]
backend = polling
enabled = true
port = all
filter = asterisk-full
logpath = /var/log/asterisk/messages
maxretry = 3
findtime = 1200
bantime = 600
```

And in `filter.d` folder I've put `asterisk-full.conf`:

```
[Definition]
failregex = .*NOTICE.* .*: Request '.*' from '.*' failed for '<HOST>:.*' .*- Failed to authenticate
            .*NOTICE.* .*: Request '.*' from '.*' failed for '<HOST>:.*' .*- No matching endpoint found
ignoreregex =
```

The problem is, if I try the filter with the command

```
sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/asterisk/full /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/asterisk-full.conf
```

It does work, it correctly sees the logfile and matches the line, but the problem is that the jail is not active in fail2ban.

This is what I get launching `fail2ban-client status`:

```
Status
|- Number of jail:      1
`- Jail list:   sshd
```

And the Asterisk jail is not listed.

I ran the commands `fail2ban-client reload` and `systemctl restart fail2ban`, but to no avail.

SO is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

The jail isn't started because files inside `jail.d` must end with either `.local` or `.conf`. So rename your `asterisk.full` to, say, `asterisk.conf`.

Also don't use both `jail.local` and `jail.d/*` files at the same time for a particular jail; either use one or the other. In this case just remove the jail.local file.

Remove from asterisk.conf any redundant parts and include only parameters which will hold custom non-standard values (parameters that are omitted will be taken from the defaults in `jail.conf`, which should stay untouched).

```
[asterisk]
backend = polling
enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/asterisk/full
maxretry = 3
findtime = 1200
bantime = 600
```

Rename your `asterisk-full.conf` inside `filter.d` folder to `asterisk.conf` (this isn't necessary but you'd have to provide the `filter` parameter in `jail.d/asterisk.conf` with that value, otherwise it defaults to the jail's name, in this case just `asterisk`).

Check if parameters have values that indeed meet your criteria (for example if backend is polling, or if logpath has the correct path, etc). Restart fail2ban and check its status, then the new jail should be listed.